# A button is stuck in the same position - swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

[image]
I want to move the button to the left. Every time I try to drag it to the left I can seem to move it as it just resets. This is in a navigation controller. Thank you in advance

Comment: Which button specifically are you trying to move to the left?

Comment: the back button on the left

Comment: you will use your custom navigation so you can move your button in any place.

Comment: what do you mean you will use your custom navigation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to drag a new button to the left side of the navigation controller, consider using `Bar Button Item`. If you want to do it programmatically: `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(yourCustomMethod))`